# Regular Expressions Negation String

Tags: regex, string, notepad++, regex-negation

I want a regular expression to find all the tr tags that do not contain td

```
<tr asdf>
<td>
<hello>
</td>
</tr>
<tr asdf>
</tr>
```

I only want the bottom 2 lines in the code to be found. Here is the template of the regular expression:

```
<tr.*?>(Cannot figure this section out)</tr>
```

Comment: [Another day, another poor soul trying to parse HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/399649) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this kind of pattern:

```
<tr[^>]*>(?>[^<]+|<(?!td\b|/tr>))*</tr>
```

Pattern description:

```
<tr[^>]*>          # a tr tag with whatever you want inside
(?>                # open an atomic group (like a non-capturing
                   # group but forbids backtracking once it is closed)
    [^<]+          # all that is not a <
  |                # OR
    <(?!td\b|/tr>) # a < not followed by td or /tr>
)*                 # zero or more times
</tr>
```

or this one (slower, most of the time):

```
(?s)<tr[^>]*>(?:(?!<td\b).)*?</tr>
```

Comment: @developer234: however, note that these two patterns don't work if you have nested tr tags.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: There are many different situations with which you need to deal and that needs reflexion, but the reflexion stops where the dogma begins.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr[^>]*>((?!<\/tr>|<td>|<\/td>).)*<\/tr>
```

Try this.Set `g` and `s` flag.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/uH3tP3/12